# Accessing custom objects in DomainService from client

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, entity-framework

I am using Domain Service to fetch data from database from Silverlight Client.

In DomainService1.cs, I have added the following:

```
[EnableClientAccess()]
public class Product
{
    public int productID;
    public string productName;        
    public List<Part> Parts = new List<Part>(); //Part is already present in Model designer
}
```

In DomainService1 class I added a new method to retrive a collection of the custom class object:

```
[EnableClientAccess()]
 public class DomainService1 : LinqToEntitiesDomainService<HELPERDBNEWEntities1>
 {
     ...
        public List<Product> GetProductsList(...)
        {
            List<Product> resultProducts = new List<Product>();
            ...
            return resultProducts;
        }
 }
```

From the silverlight client I am trying to access that method:

```
DomainService1 ds1 = new DomainService1();
var allproductList = ds1.GetProductsList(...);
ds1.Load<SLProduct>(allproductList).Completed += new EventHandler(Load_Completed); //Not correct usage
```

However it is not the correct way to call the new method. The reason I added a new class Product in DomainServices.cs is to have an efficient grouping. I cannot achieve the same using the model classes auto-generated by the entity framework.

How call I call the new method from the client?

Comment: What do you mean by not correct way, it is the only way.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a similar question with an answer here:

[Can a DomainService return a single custom type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849581/can-a-domainservice-return-a-single-custom-type)

Also, here is some discussion about the overall problem of adding custom methods in a Domain Service:

http://forums.silverlight.net/t/159292.aspx/1

Answer (score 1):

While I don't know what you mean by "it is not the correct way to call the new method", or if you're getting any errors, I thought maybe posting some working code might help.

My POCO

```
    public class GraphPointWithMeta
{
    [Key]
    public Guid PK { get; set; }
    public string SeriesName { get; set; } 
    public string EntityName { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }

    public GraphPointWithMeta(string seriesName, string entityName, double amount)
    {
        PK = Guid.NewGuid();
        SeriesName = seriesName;
        EntityName = entityName;
        Amount = amount;
    }

    // Default ctor required.
    public GraphPointWithMeta()
    {
        PK = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}
```

A method in the domain service (EnableClientAccess decorates the class)

```
        public IEnumerable<GraphPointWithMeta> CallingActivityByCommercial()
    {
        List<GraphPointWithMeta> gps = new List<GraphPointWithMeta>();
        // ...
        return gps;
    }
```

Called from the Silverlight client like

```
ctx1.Load(ctx1.CallingActivityByCommercialQuery(), CallingActivityCompleted, null);
```

client call back method

```
        private void CallingActivityCompleted(LoadOperation<GraphPointWithMeta> lo)
    {
        // lo.Entities is an IEnumerable<GraphPointWithMeta>            
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your Product class is an actual entity or not.  From the way it is defined, it does not appear to be an entity.  My answer is assuming it is not an entity.  You will need to apply the DataMemberAttribute for your Product properties, and you wouldn't load the product list - load is for Entity Queries (IQueryable on the service side).  You would just invoke it like this (client side):

```
void GetProductList( Action<InvokeOperation<List<Product>>> callback)
{
    DomainService ds1 = new DomainService();
    ds1.GetProductsList(callback, null);//invoke operation call
}
```

And the domain service's (server side) method needs the InvokeAttribute and would look like this:

```
[EnableClientAccess]
public class MyDomainService
{
    [Invoke]
    public List<Product> GetProductList()
    {
        var list = new List<Product>();
        ...
        return list;
    }
}
```

And here is how your Product class might be defined (if it is not an entity):

```
public class Product
{
   [DataMember]
   public int productID;
   [DataMember]
   public string productName;        
   [DataMember]
   public List<Part> Parts = new List<Part>(); // you might have some trouble here.
                           //not sure if any other attributes are needed for Parts,
                           //since you said this is an entity; also not sure if you 
                           //can even have a list of entities or it needs to be an
                           //entity collection or what it needs to be.  You might
                           //have to make two separate calls - one to get the products
                           //and then one to get the parts.
}
```

Like I said, i am not sure what Product inherits from... Hope this helps.