# Can a Domain Service return a custom class instance?

Tags: c#, .net

My silverlight application is fetching data from the database via RIA services. I am able to write methods that return Entities with LINQ. But I have a requirement to issue multiple queries to the model and populate a custom object from the returned records and return it.

If I define the custom class in DomainService file, how can I access it in Silverlight client?

EDIT:
I am able to access the class, but the properties are not visible and I am not sure how to call the method that returns the custom class. Is there any samples I can get? MSDN examples are too tied with Entity Framework and it deals with returning entities. I need to manipulate the entities and return my own class and make it usable in silverlight client.

EDIT 2: Should the custom class be defined as an Entity?

Comment: I have a very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876868/accessing-custom-objects-in-domainservice-from-client which is on bounty.

Comment: Yes, I have mostly the same question

Comment: I posted some working code over in darthvader's thread. Not sure if it will help, but worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, the class you defined does not show up in the generated code. If that's the case, I've gotten it to work by exposing it:

```
// Doing this just so we can make Hierarchy visible to the RIA genereated
// code on the client.
public void TestForHeirarchy(Hierarchy h) { }
```

Not sure if that's the best/proper way, but it did what I needed.